# How to open multiple doc file in python and parse email ID from them and write in csv?

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to extract email id from 1000 word document files and produce a csv file in python.

Comment: Go right ahead!

Comment: I am looking for a advise or code snippet that can perform this task edficiently

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is detecting **Email Address**,this `Regex` code will help you:

```
[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]
```

and you should use it in python like this:

```
import re

out= re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', YourTextFile) 
print(str(out))
```

and the other part for reading csv or writing in it you can use this [link](https://realpython.com/python-csv/).